# Copy file in /system folder with Runtime.getRuntime().exec

Tags: android, file, copy

I have to copy a `.mp3` file in `/system/media/audio/ringtones` and then set as default ringtone. 
I try to copy it with:

```
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mount -o rw, remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock4 /system");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cp /storage/sdcard0/MyFile.mp3 /system/media/audio/ringtones/MyFile.mp3");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mount -o ro, remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock4 /system");
```

but nothing happen, even if i manually change permission of `/system` directory with root explorer **( i'm running a cyanogenmod 10.2 on galaxy s2 )** ... why?

If i try to copy in other directory **( i.e. /storage/sdcard0/folder/ )** all works fine. Some hint will be appreciated. After that, how can i set an `.mp3` file located somewhere in the file system as default ringtone?

Comment: do you have a root permissions on your phone?

Comment: Yes, i run the cyanogenmod, it's rooted :D

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar issue with replacing the bootanimation.zip and this is how I fixed it. Hope it helps somebody.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mount -o remount,rw system /system");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cp /storage/emulated/0/bootanimation/bootanimation.zip /system/media/bootanimation.zip");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 644 /system/media/bootanimation.zip");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mount -o remount,ro system /system");
```